# GSUB replace 3 or more repeating characters

Tags: ruby, gsub

A little help would be appreciated with a gsub regex in ruby.  I need to replace 3 or more forward slashes "//////" with just 2 forward slashes "//" in a string of text. However, a single forward slash and double forward slashes should be skipped and left as is.

my data looks like this `jeep/grand cherokee////////hyundai/////harley davidson//bmw` and should be converted to `jeep/grand cherokee//hyundai//harley davidson//bmw`

I don't have much experience with using gsub regex's, here's a few things I've tried but they either strip out all forward slashes or add in too many.

```
  vehicles = vehicles.gsub(/[\/\\1{3,}]/, "")

  vehicles = vehicles.gsub(/[\/\2+]/, "//")

  vehicles = vehicles.gsub(/[\/{3,}]/,"//")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enclose the whole pattern inside square brackets, you make it match a single char.

Your regexps mean:

- `[\/\\1{3,}]` - a single char, `/`, `\`, `1`, `{`, `3`, `,` or `}`
- `[\/\2+]` - `/`, `\u0002` char or `+`
- `[\/{3,}]` - `/`, `{`, `3`, `,` or `}`

You can use

```rb
s.gsub(/\/{3,}/, '//')
```

See the [Ruby demo online](https://ideone.com/8nQrSs).